# Should I mention I am currently a student at an upcoming interview?

Tags: interviewing, new-job

I have been invited for an interview that is very important for me. I already have a Bachelors degree, but I am currently working on my Masters. I am finished with the classes besides the finals coming up. If they were to offer me a job, I will need to take a few half days off within the first 2 weeks of employment.

Should I mention this during the interview?

Comment: There is a bit of disconnect for me. Did you put on your resume that you were pursuing a masters degree?

Comment: No. I didn't mention it on my reaume.

Comment: I recommend you add your masters degree to your resume... remember to put your expected graduation date.

Comment: You are over thinking the situation.  When you are offered the job, and are at the stage when you can start, indicate when you can start after your finals.

Comment: Thanks everybody for comments and tips. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you should tell them. "Nearly finished a master" is better than "finished a bachelor and then just sat around for a year doing nothing in particular".

For the exams, you could simply ask to postpone your start date by two weeks - but *don't* bring this up until they have *decided to give you an offer* and moved on to discussing specifics. A later start date would leave you with free time to study to make sure you actually finish the degree. Starting a new job is usually quite draining and once the exams are done you would be able to focus entirely on your new position.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I think they will hire imidiately if I pass the interview. There is only one interview.

Comment: The last thing you want to do is ask for “half days” when you first start a job.  Ask to start after finals, explain the situation, you need the time to finish your masters degree.

Comment: When recruiting for a qualified position (one requiring a degree or specific experience) most companies are quite flexible with dates *if they believe they have found the right candidate* (e.g. my employer has a lead time of ~3 months, since that is the standard period of notice for the industry). When I started my current job I was unemployed but requested an extra month to prepare since I was currently moving and also had some personal trips planned. It's best to just be clear about your *intentions* and suggest a date when you are ready to get started for real.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your comment helped me a lot. It was really helpful.